# how to get all data from db between two dates in PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am failing to receive all data which are inserted between two dates. for example start date: 2017-01-15 - 2018-05-15 : end date.

I want to get all wages of people who have worked for a specific project during that period of time, and my code is this so far:

```
$project = Project::find($project_id);
$projectStartDate = $project->start_date;
$projectEndDate = $project->end_date;

$usersOfProject = $project->users()->get();

foreach ($usersOfProject as $userOfProject){

    $ids = $userOfProject->id;

    $userWages = UserWage::where('user_id',$ids)->where('start_date','<=', $projectStartDate)->where('end_date','>=',$projectEndDate)->get();
    foreach ($userWages as $userWage){
        $wage= wage + $userWage->value;

        return $wage;
    }
}
```

when I `dd($ids);` it shows only 1 user that's working for the project, not all of them. (currently two working on it).

fillables for UserWages are these:

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'value', 'currency', 'user_id', 'start_date', 'end_date',
    ];
```

, Projects:

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'value', 'client_id','currency','',
    ];
```

, User:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'status_id','mobile', 'role',
    ];
```

The purpose of all this is that I am trying to get the wage of every user who has worked for this project during the of project start and project end.
Wages might change from month to month, and so the exchange rate of them (payment can be done in USD, Euro or Albanian Lek);

I am trying to get all wages of users who are part of the project, and calculate data, for each pay that they might have had. with the exchange rate of that month, exchange rate can be filled by the admin.

code for Exchange rate is this:

```
    function exchangeRate($value, $currency){
 $getCurrency = Exchange::whereDate('date','2017-11-30'); //This is just for test to calculate wages with exchange rate of november 30, will do with carbon to get last date of month.

        $dollar = $getCurrency->dollar_lek;
        $euro = $getCurrency->euro_lek;

        if ($currency == 'ALL') {
            $value = $value;
        } elseif ($currency == 'USD') {
            $value = $value * $dollar;
        } else {
            $value = $value * $euro;
        }
    }
```

fillables for Exchange rate are

```
protected $fillable =[

    'euro_lek', 'dollar_lek', 'date',
];
```

Comment: Why you have return in the second foreach loop? It will only return one record. Query is ok. You have to elaborate your question.

Comment: @forexknight hey, I updated the question, can you check again?

Comment: When you do `dd($ids)` the loop halts at the first iteration. That's why it show only one user. use `dump($ids)` instead.

Comment: You should show us the deepth of this: `$usersOfProject = $project->users()->get();`

Comment: @Gayan to check how many users are, but yes I got your point, it was a mistake I didnt thought, but when I `dd($userWage->value)` I get nothing

Comment: @forexknight I get an array of two (` #items: array:2`). it works, since there are only two users working for this project

Comment: Give a look at the new answer. It should be the final solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I've found what's wrong.
You should use **whereIn** to get all user wages.

Change this:

```
$project = Project::find($project_id);
$projectStartDate = $project->start_date;
$projectEndDate = $project->end_date;

$usersOfProject = $project->users()->get();

foreach ($usersOfProject as $userOfProject){

    $ids = $userOfProject->id;

$userWages = UserWage::where('user_id',$ids)->where('start_date','<=', $projectStartDate)->where('end_date','>=',$projectEndDate)->get();
foreach ($userWages as $userWage){
    $wage= wage + $userWage->value;
    //it should be pushed into array and not returning single value.
    return $wage;
}
```

}

Into this:

```
$project = Project::find($project_id);
$projectStartDate = $project->start_date;
$projectEndDate = $project->end_date;
$wages = array();

$usersOfProject = $project->users()->get();

foreach ($usersOfProject as $userOfProject){

    $userWages = UserWage::whereIn('user_id',$usersOfProject>pluck('id')->toArray())->where('start_date','<=', $projectStartDate)->where('end_date','>=',$projectEndDate)->get();
    foreach ($userWages as $userWage){
        $wage= wage + $userWage->value;
        array_push($wages, $wage);
    }
}

return $wages;
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

it says that its an error in helpers line 547 when I only have 540 lines in helpers

Comment: Yes, actually we should get only id of the user and then convert it to array.

Comment: I forgot to add `$wage=$wage + $userWage->value;` I had it `$wage=wage + $userWage->value;' anyway, when it shouldnt be there at all. 

because it sums all wages.

Comment: so it works, but should I create a function to convert it all for the last exchange rate of the month? or is it possible to be done inside this function?

Comment: It's better to create new function. Also if the answer is corrent you should check it as corrent answer, to show other users that the case has been solved.

Comment: did, and thanks for the answer, but how to get the date from wage? I am doing something like this `$wageDate = $userWage->date;` and push it to the array but it shows null

Comment: Wait. `UserWage` modal has only start_date and end_date values. So you can only take these values. I don't get what you would like to achieve.

Comment: forexknight, Im creating a new post about it, I will post the link I guess here

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052417/calculate-wage-of-user-on-different-exchange-rates-in-php-laravel

Answer (score 0):

I would make it in a different way:

```
    $project = Project::find($project_id);
    $projectStartDate = Carbon::parse($project->start_date)->startOfDay();
    $projectEndDate =  Carbon::parse($project->end_date)->endOfDay();

    $usersOfProject = $project->users()->get();


    $userWages = UserWage::whereIn('user_id',$usersOfProject->pluck('id')->toArray())->whereBetween('start_date',[ $projectStartDate,$projectEndDate])->whereBetween('end_date',[ $projectStartDate,$projectEndDate])->get();

    $wages = [];
    foreach ($userWages as $userWage){
        $wage= wage + $userWage->value;
        array_push($wages,$wage);
    }

    dd($userWages,$wages);
```

Comment: get an empty array, but I thought that it might be the problem in date, so I checked out. 

if I enter manually dates at `$userWage` it gets data