# Calculate wage of user on different exchange rates in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am failing to understand(and write) the algorithm that needs to convert wage of user from Euro to USD or ALL (Albanian Lek).

With this code, I get all the users who are part of a project (more info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049531/how-to-get-all-data-from-db-between-two-dates-in-php-laravel))

```
function calculatingWages($project_id)
{
    $project = Project::find($project_id);
    $projectStartDate = Carbon::parse($project->start_date)->startOfDay();
    $projectEndDate =  Carbon::parse($project->end_date)->endOfDay();

    $usersOfProject = $project->users()->get();


    $userWages = UserWage::whereIn('user_id',$usersOfProject->pluck('id')->toArray())->whereBetween('start_date',[ $projectStartDate,$projectEndDate])->whereBetween('end_date',[ $projectStartDate,$projectEndDate])->get();

    $wages = [];

    $sumTotalWage=0;
    foreach ($userWages as $userWage){
        $wage=  $userWage->value;
        $wageDate = $userWage->end_date;
        $wageCurrency = $userWage->currency;

        convertingALL($userWage->value, $userWage->currency, $userWage->end_date);
        array_push($wages,$wage,$wageDate, $wageCurrency);
    }

}
```

this does the trick, it gets user wages, wage end date and their currency.
Now at Exchanges, admin adds an exchange every last day of the month,

User can have the same wage for 5 months, but during those months,  exchange rate can change, so I want to calculate the total price after being multiplied with the rates of every month.

for multiplication I've designed this code:

```
  $getCurrency = Exchange::all()->last()->get(); // Added like this so it wont show error, but will do with carbon, like Carbon::lastDayOfMonth

        $dollar = $getCurrency->dollar_lek;
        $euro = $getCurrency->euro_lek;

        if ($currency == 'ALL') {
            $value = $value;
        } elseif ($currency == 'USD') {
            $value = $value * $dollar;
        } else {
            $value = $value * $euro;
        }
```

But I cant understand how to get every month that wage is and multiply it with the value of exchange for that month.

Also, Users wage might change. when the estimated time of his wage is over, admin adds a new wage for him. Not sure if this is needed or not.

Fillables for Exchange are this

```
protected $fillable =[
        'euro_lek', 'dollar_lek', 'date',
    ];
```

Comment: I think you have to restructure your database with optimization and relationship among them.

Comment: relationships are set between user and project, and wages, should I add any relationship with exchange rate too?

Comment: That's fine, but according to your requirement of monthly varying wage structure, you need to make optimized database. I think current one is not sufficient

Comment: can you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: It's long to interpret here in comment.

Comment: I've done such salary based system before

Comment: send it as an answer then please

Comment: I can't add like an answer since it's not the answer to the question. It's a suggestion :D

Comment: you are right, I gave a better thought to what you said and come up with a solution with it. so thanks? I guess?

Comment: Analyze your DB structure and make tables and column appropriately